# Is jquery or nodejs supported by Instruments in Xcode for UI Automation

Tags: jquery, node.js, xcode, user-interface, ios-ui-automation

Is jquery or nodejs supported by Instruments in Xcode for UI Automation ?

I need to use some of the inbuilt functions of jQuery in Instruments code. 
Please guide if jquery or node js, is supported by instruments.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a JavaScript library created to make traversing the DOM tree and handling HTML elements easier. Since global variables such as 'document' don't exist in Instruments it is very likely that the library won't work. However, even if it did I don't think you would get any benefit from it. Instruments and its element tree are very different in purpose and design from an HTML document.

As for nodejs it is designed to be a network/server side javascript library. It may not throw an error in Instruments but I don't see what benefit it will offer you.